# Add modules with yarn, Less compiler error

Tags: less, phpstorm, webstorm, yarnpkg

I added an example module:

```
yarn add jquery.fancytree
```

I get many errors in PhpStorm with Less file watcher:

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc --no-color bootstrap-datetimepicker-build.less
FileError: 'bootstrap/less/variables.less' wasn't found. Tried - /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/crm4/web/js/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/bootstrap/less/variables.less,/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/crm4/web/js/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/bootstrap/less/variables.less,/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/crm4/web/js/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/node_modules/bootstrap/less/variables.less,bootstrap/less/variables.less in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/crm4/web/js/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/bootstrap-datetimepicker-build.less on line 2, column 1:
1 // Import bootstrap variables including default color palette and fonts
2 @import "bootstrap/less/variables.less";
3
```

This is not the first time, I get this error sometimes in different modules.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where this import comes from; what is `bootstrap` - is it an npm module? Anyway, you need to let the compiler know where you look for your files. To do this, try using `--include-path` option, like `--include-path=$ProjectFileDir$/node_modules` (has to be added to file watcher arguments). See http://lesscss.org/usage/